# VHDX drive space being consumed

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ntfs, deduplication

I have a host running Server 2012 R2, and a file server VM also running 2012 R2.

The VM has 3 drives, `OS.vhdx`, `file-1.vhdx` and `file2.vhdx`.

Dedupe is running inside the VM on `file-1.vhdx` and `file2.vhdx`.

I have checked via file shares and no-one is using the server, to be sure, i disabled file and print sharing - in short, no files are being physically added to the drive by any user.

For some reason `file-1.vhdx` is continuously expanding out at around 5GB per hour, even when there is no data being written to it.

I have disabled dedupe and appears data is being expanded regardless.

I ran a utility called `OpenedFilesView.exe`, and saw a stack of files open on the drive that `file-1.vhdx` maps to, and they are pointing to the the `fsdmhost.exe` process.

Could this be a Windows bug? Will dedupe not use existing space on the vhdx, or will it cause it to expand?

Any recommendations please on how to stop this forever growing drive?

Answer (score 1):

Download this tool to reveal the source of the problem and which directory is eating your disk

```
https://windirstat.net/
```

once you know the source you can solve

Comment: I use this software, too: it could provide some insight and starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no files are being added to the file system, this does appear to be dedupe related since disabling and rebooting the vhdx is no longer growing.